# CTRL + L does not work in solaris, nor does clear command

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, solaris

I'm trying to get <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to work under solaris 10,

So I tried to add a binding to `~/.inputrc`

```
"\C-l":'clear\n'
```

Well it did bind to the `clear` command, but `clear` command itself fails, sigh.

Any ideas?

P.S I've tried to set `TERM` variable to `linux` or `xterm`, which does not help.

[image]

**EDIT**

Instead of modifying `inputrc`, looks like I should do

```
export TERM=xterm
```

Solaris simply does not work with `xterm-256color`, which is set by iTerm2 by default.

Comment: Does `printf '\033\143'` clear your screen?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. For bash: `echo $'"\C-l": "printf \'\\033c\'\015"' >> ~/.inputrc`, then `ctrl-x ctrl-r` to re-read `~/.inputrc`, then try `ctrl-l`.

Comment: bash ignores a missing terminal description; clear doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to bind it like this:

```
"\C-l":clear-screen
```

That did work at least for me on my CentOS 7 test machine.
Unfortunately I could not find any manual reference for this now, but there is this mentioned on bash man page:

```
       clear-screen (C-l)
          Clear the screen leaving the current line at the top of the screen.  With an argument,  refresh  the
          current line without clearing the screen.
```

Comment: Hmm, no effect on solaris. I've logged out and logged in again to confirm that.

Comment: Nonetheless, this is the right thing to do and the other answer is just a bodge.  Given that the `clear` command doesn't clear the screen, the problem that you have is some sort of terminfo problem.  **That** is what you need to fix, leaving the readline configuration with the normal binding, as given here.  Unfortunately, you haven't shown answerers the important stuff: what terminal type you are using, what terminal emulator program you are using, and a syscall trace (or hex dump of the of the output) of the `clear` command.  Hence answers that don't address terminfo at all.

Comment: @JdeBP so how to fix the terminfo?

Comment: @JdeBP never mind, setting TERM to xterm fixed the problem, no additional binding required